# How do I test a single migration in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, phpunit

Is there a concise way to test Laravel migrations? I want establish the database up to the point of my new migration (including seeds etc) and then run my new migration and check the tests I have written for my seed data. The main issue is that I need to create my factory objects **before** the new migration is run, but **after** the other migrations run (creating all the original tables etc). As far as I know the only way to do it is either run every migration individually with the `--path` option, create the factory objects and finally run my new migration. Is there a better way?